# error en PrepareStatement

Tags: java, prepared-statements

```
private void BtnConectarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        try{ 
           Connection con = getConection();//llamo a la conexion
           String sql = "Select * from personas";
           PreparedStatement ps ; 
             ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Me da error como que no encuentra el método prepareStatement y queda marcado en rojo. ¿Le sucedió a alguien y cómo lo resolvió? le estaré muy agradecido.

```
      ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Esa es la línea que me da el error.

Comment: y con.createStatement() aparece ?

Comment: ¿Que paquete estas usando para el `Connection`? ¿Puedes copiar y pegar el error en la pregunta?

Comment: los import que uso son;                                        
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;       me da error que no encuentra el metodo      prepare Statement      :cannoy find simbol : method prepareStatement(String)                                                      location:variable con oftype Connection

Comment: Comprueba que usas la interfaz java.sql.Connection

Comment: uso el jdbc 5.1.48 todavia no use el executeStatement()

Comment: Prepar**edS**tatment or Prepar**eS**tament

Comment: Ambos. Está correcto en la pregunta.